# passing array to filter twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a twig filter defined as follows:

```
'namefilter' => new \Twig_Filter_Method ($this, 'myFilter')
```

and the head of the function like this:

```
public function myFilter ($text, $array = array('defect'))
```

how could call from twig to the filter.
how could create a twig array to pass it to the filter?

greetings and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{ 'text'|namefilter(['notdefect']) }}
```

Or:

```
{% set arr = ['notdefect'] %}
{{ 'text'|namefilter(arr) }}
```

Note: You should use [Twig_SimpleFilter](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/SimpleFilter.php), instead of [Twig_Filter_Method](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Filter/Method.php) which is deprecated and will be removed entirely in version 2.0:

```
new \Twig_SimpleFilter('namefilter', 'myFilter');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ 'text'|nameFilter(['defect']) }}
```